# Need to apply multiple filter on an excel column via VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I need to apply multiple filter to an excel column using VBScript (VBS File, not VBA).

My sheet is like this:

```
Order    Line Status

Ord1     Awaiting Return
Ord2     Entered
Ord3     Shipped
Ord4     Fulfilled
Ord5     Awaiting return
Ord6     Shipped
```

I need to apply filter on Line Status column where i need to show columns

'Awaiting Return','Entered','Shipped'.

I wrote the following code:

```
Set objSrcExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objSrcExcel.Visible = False obj
objSrcExcel.DisplayAlerts = False  

Set objSrcWorkbook = objSrcExcel.Workbooks.Open(srcFile)
Set objSrcWorksheet = objSrcWorkbook.Worksheets(srcSheet)

With objXLAppWs
.Range("K1" ).AutoFilter 11,"=Awaiting Return",2 , "=Entered",2 , "=Awaiting Shipping" 
End With
```

But it results with error.

I am able to apply filter using the above the code, with two filter options i.e. 'Awaiting Return' and 'Entered' but when i try to go for 3 values, it erred.

```
//This code works for 2 filter values
     With objXLAppWs
     .Range("K1" ).AutoFilter 11,"=Awaiting Return",2 , "=Entered" 
     End With
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Prachi

Answer (score 2):

There are only two criterias for direct combination. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx.

You have to use an array as `Criteria1` and operator `xlFilterValues`= 7.

```
...
.Range("K1").AutoFilter 11, Array("Awaiting Return", "Entered", "Awaiting Shipping"), 7
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
objSrcExcel.cell(1,no. of columns).autofilter 1(column_num),data_you_need to filter
objSrcExcel.cell(1,no. of columns).autofilter 2(column_num),data_you_need to filter
```

and so on you can apply multiple filter